# Accessing google drive with keys instead of login credentials

Tags: google-drive

I'm hoping to set up an automatic backup of my important documents on google drive. The idea is to have a dedicated backup computer which will copy the data from google drive to an external hard disk.

For this to run automatically, the backup computer must log into google drive without me inserting the credentials in a browser.

The setup for automatic backup would involve a headless RPi running [rclone](https://rclone.org/) periodically to make a backup if there is new data on the drive.

Google derive seems to have a concept of a [Service Account](https://rclone.org/drive/#service-account-support) but I don't understand yet what does that mean implementation wise for my use case.

In the ideal case, google drive would offer a text form where I could enter a public key. Anything with the correct private key would have access (king of like how github does it).

Is there a way to authenticate a personal google drive account without credentials?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you use to set up the automatic backup? Will you Backup and Sync, File Stream or another thing? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Yes, Google App Scripts can use a token to authenticate a log-in, and the token can be refreshed.